# What do I call a generalization of a fork?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

In Category Theory, we call a [fork](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fork) a diagram

$$X\xrightarrow{\;e\;}A\begin{array}{c}
\xrightarrow{\;f\;}\\
\xrightarrow[\;g\;]{}
\end{array}B$$

that commutes, i.e. $f \circ e = g \circ e$.

1. In this context, what can we call $e$? Is there a proper name for it? I know it is not necessarily an equalizer of $f$ and $g$.
2. What would I call a generalization of this concept in the following sense: given objects $A$ and $B$, a non-empty subset $H \subseteq Hom(A,B)$ and a morphism $e : X \rightarrow A$, we have that

   $$\forall f,\, g\, \in H.\, f \circ e = g \circ e$$

In particular, I am interested in the case where $H$ is the set of isomorphisms between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: 2. I would call it an $H$-pronged fork.

Comment: (Can't help saying "spork". Sorry...)

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Yes, thanks. I fixed the question.

Comment: I took the liberty of removing your edit notice, as I found it confusing. Besides, if someone wants to see all the versions of the question, they can just click on the "edited [time] ago".

Comment: 1. Though it may be pushing the cutlery metaphor too far, I would call it a handle.

Comment: I would call $e$ something along the line '*equator*', '*equalizing* map'..

Comment: The idea of $e$ is that of a (generalized) **element**.